# Find the nearest restaurant given locations

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Write a function that finds the nearest restaurants and returns the nearest target number of restaurants provided. allLocations is an array of coordinates [x,y]. Distance is calculated by sqrt(x^2 + y^2). User location always starts at [0,0]

```
function nearestResturants(totralRes,allLocations,toReturn)
```

sample input: nearestResturants(4,[[1,1],[4,2],[7,8],[9,3]],2)

My plan was to create an array of objects with location and the calculated distance for each coordinate. Then return a sorted array containing coordinates and return first `toReturn` coordinates.

```
function nearestResturants(totralRes,allLocations,toReturn) {
  const locs = allLocations.map(location => {
    return {
      loc: location,
      distance: calcDistance(location)
    }
 });
}

function calcDistance(location) {
  var dis = Math.pow(location[0],2) + Math.pow(location[1],2);
  return Math.sqrt(dis);
}
```

The output for locs is also weird because it returs [object object]
1. Is there is faster way to do this? Because this would lead to at least `O(nlogn)`.
2. how to do this better and easier?

Comment: Where is sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 ways to solve this:

1. sort the array you build and return the first `k` elements - **`O(nlogn)`**
2. Use Heap to get the smallest `k` element - **`O(n + logn*k).`**

Consider the following method:

```
function nearestResturantsWithSort(totralRes,allLocations,toReturn) {
    const locs = allLocations.map(location => {
        return {loc: location, distance: calcDistance(location)};
    });
    locs.sort((a,b) => (a.distance > b.distance) ? 1 : ((b.distance > a.distance) ? -1 : 0));
    return locs.slice(0, toReturn);
}

var Heap = require('heap');
function nearestResturantsWithHeap(totralRes,allLocations,toReturn) {
    let locs = allLocations.map(location => {
        return {loc: location, distance: calcDistance(location)};
    });
    return Heap.nsmallest(locs, toReturn, function(a, b) { return a.distance - b.distance; });
}

function calcDistance(location) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(location[0],2) + Math.pow(location[1],2));
}
```

I would recommend of-course the second method (Heap)

Comment: If the heap library is using an optimal heap algorithm, the heap solution is O(n + logn * k). O(n) is building a heap and O(logn) is one pop.

Comment: Which is enen better then `O(n*k)` - thanks for the comment